# WCF Client Error : target refused

Tags: c#, wcf, tcpclient

I have a interface, interface implementation and the client
Now when I try to host the service and use the client in the same console application. I get the following error:

> "Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8000/ClassAService. The
>   connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0150000. TCP
>   error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000".

I surfed and found that it is due to port being blocked by Firewall. But its not the same with my case. I verified. It didn't work even after change the port numbers

I have posted the code and the app.config in
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1015959/WCF-Client-Error-Could-not-connect-to-net-tcp-No-c?arn=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't instantiate the ServiceHost in a using clause in ClassA.StartServiceHost. This will make the ServiceHost dispose before that method is even exited.

Consider creating the ServiceHost instance before the Console.ReadLine statement in the console application, and then call ServiceHost.Close and ServiceHost.Dispose after the Console.ReadLine statement. The ServiceHost must be alive (not disposed) as long as you want the service to run.